# Gradle: No resource type specified (at 'text' with value '@{user.name}'). Databinding not working

Tags: android, data-binding

Im trying to add proper databinding functionality into my project, but for some reason it's still fail.

`build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc4"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "boilerplate"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
}
```

layout file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <data>
        <variable name="user" type="boilerplate.UserModel"/>
    </data>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:onClick="OnBtnClick7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText3"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@{user.name}"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@{user.email}"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@{user.password}"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when trying to build the code I have this errors:

`Error:(23, 34) Gradle: No resource type specified (at 'text' with value '@{user.name}').
Error:(38, 35) Gradle: No resource type specified (at 'text' with value '@{user.email}').
Error:(49, 38) Gradle: No resource type specified (at 'text' with value '@{user.password}').`

What should i do to fix this?

Comment: replace   this <variable name="user" type="boilerplate.UserModel"/> to <variable name="user" type="io.centaurea.boilerplate.UserModel"/>

Comment: this will not help. I just remove my companies extension from code and forget remove it from graddle. in real life they are the same

Comment: is this your main package name -boilerplate?

Comment: try to `clean` the project and `rebuild` the project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is not the proper structure for the layout file. For a data binding layout file:

- The root element is `<layout>` (not `<LinearLayout>`)
- The `<layout>` has a child `<data>` element, akin to yours
- Your views then follow the `<data>` element as a child of `<layout>`

For example, in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DataBinding/Basic), I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <data>

    <variable
      name="item"
      type="com.commonsware.android.databind.basic.Item"/>
  </data>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/icon"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/icon"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/icon"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
      android:padding="8dip"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
      android:text="@{item.title}"
      android:textSize="20sp"/>

  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. Already find this myself. However I was confused that there is no such instructions in official guides  or atleast I don't find any. Could you please point me to some docs where described which layout I need to use for which case?

Comment: @silent_coder: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#writing_expressions "Data-binding layout files are slightly different and start with a root tag of layout followed by a data element and a view root element. This view element is what your root would be in a non-binding layout file. "