# Android data binding: Error: No resource type specified

Tags: android-databinding

I am having a problem of data binding with following objects. I have an object class call ScanInfo look like this.

```
    public class ScanInfo extends BaseObservable implements Parcelable {
    private BarcodeItem barcodeItem;
    private ParcelInfo parcelInfo;
    private int childCount = 0;
    private boolean showQuantity;
    private boolean showDeviation;
    private boolean hasParcel;
    private boolean hasBarcode;

    public ScanInfo(BarcodeItem barcodeItem) {
        this.barcodeItem = barcodeItem;
    }

    public ScanInfo(ParcelInfo parcelInfo) {
        this.parcelInfo = parcelInfo;
    }

    public ScanInfo(BarcodeItem barcodeItem, ParcelInfo parcelInfo) {
        this.barcodeItem = barcodeItem;
        this.parcelInfo = parcelInfo;
    }

    @Bindable
    public BarcodeItem getBarcodeItem() {
        return barcodeItem;
    }

    public void setBarcodeItem(BarcodeItem barcodeItem) {
        this.barcodeItem = barcodeItem;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.hasBarcode);
    }

    @Bindable
    public ParcelInfo getParcelInfo() {
        return parcelInfo;
    }

    public void setParcelInfo(ParcelInfo parcelInfo) {
        this.parcelInfo = parcelInfo;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.hasParcel);
    }

    @Bindable
    public boolean isHasParcel() {
        return hasParcel;
    }

    @Bindable
    public boolean isHasBarcode() {
        return hasBarcode;
    }

    public void setChildCount(int childCount) {
        this.childCount = childCount;
    }

    public void setShowQuantity(boolean showQuantity) {
        this.showQuantity = showQuantity;
    }

    public void setShowDeviation(boolean showDeviation) {
        this.showDeviation = showDeviation;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getBarcodeContent() {
        return barcodeItem.getContent();
    }
}
```

and I have bind it to list item from adapter and adapter getView method I have done this.

```
convertView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.barcode_list_item, parent, false);
BarcodeListItemBinding binding = BarcodeListItemBinding.bind(convertView);
ScanInfo scanInfo = getItem(position);
BarcodeItem barcodeItem = scanInfo.getBarcodeItem();
if (barcodeItem != null) {
    scanInfo.setChildCount(getChildCount(barcodeItem));
    scanInfo.setShowQuantity(barcodeItem.getQuantity() > 1 || (barcodeItem.getQuantity() == 1 && _showParcelQuantityOne));
    scanInfo.setShowDeviation(_deviations != null && _deviations.size() > 0 && hasDeviation(barcodeItem));
}
binding.setScanInfo(scanInfo);
binding.executePendingBindings();
```

and list item resource file look like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <import type="xx.xxx.xxx.BarcodeItem" />

        <import type="xx.xxx.xxx.ParcelInfo" />

        <variable
            name="scanInfo"
            type="xx.xxx.xxx.ScanInfo" />
    </data>

  ...
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textBarcode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="middle"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:text="@{scanInfo.barcodeItem.content}"
                tools:text="123123123123ABABABABABABABA" />
  ...
</layout>
```

But when I compile it always gives that following error

F:\ExProjects...\event\4.171.1.0\res\layout\barcode_list_item.xml:57:31-62: AAPT: No resourc
e type specified (at 'text' with value '@{scanInfo.barcodeItem.content}').

I wonder what I have done wrong here. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you use: `dataBinding.enabled=true` in your build.gradle file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: No resource type specified (at 'text' with value '@{user.name}'). Databinding not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723767/gradle-no-resource-type-specified-at-text-with-value-user-name-databi)

Comment: @GeorgeMount yes I have used that in the module that I am working on After I added this to all other modules it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method referencing

```
android:text="@{scanInfo::getBarcodeContent}"
```